# Cutting up this background image for optimal CSS implementation?

Tags: html, css

What is the optimal way to slice up this background image for optimal CSS implementation? The designer knows no CSS and since we're not CSS experts, we're not sure of the best way to slice up the background image. The background, of course, should be fluid and scale to different monitor sizes and page lengths. At the same time, it seems sub-optimal to have one large image or multiple small images.

We don't need to support IE6.

Any advice?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By slicing, I'm not 100% sure what you want exactly. I assume you are looking for a way to stretch the Facebook part as much as needed, while still keeping the background image decent.

For most non-phone (ie desktop or tablet) screens, you could cut below the last cloud and have a repeat vertically of the blue sky background. With the CSS property background-repeat: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp
You'd have 3 divs with margin: 0:

- the hmm panabee (actual content) div, background image is the balloons, centered. You expect its height to be greater than your image's height. If you want to enforce it, there's min-height. Bottom of this image should be blue sky.
- the facebook div, can be as big as you want if you use the background-repeat with the blue sky image.
- and the footer div, with a background image of your choice, but the top of the image should be blue sky.

I think all this (except min-height, maybe?) should work on most browsers, even IE6.

Comment: Sorry, I meant how to slice the background image (e.g, sky, clouds, and balloons) into smaller images and implement the design. We were given the image but need to translate it into HTML & CSS. We know how to do the FB comments, the content (i.e., FAQ), and the footer. Just not sure how to do the sky, clouds, and balloon in the best way. Our default is what you proposed -- create a big image and repeat vertically. Is this the best way?

Comment: OK, I understand now. I think Isaac Lubow's solution is elegant and fits your problem. FF3.5 and IE7 and IE8 not compatible, though: http://caniuse.com/#search=multiple%20background

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 supports [multiple overlapping background images](http://css-tricks.com/8596-stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/) (you'd want them to be transparent PNGs or similar), as well as the `background-size` property allowing you to adapt to different window sizes. It seems to me this would solve your problem exactly.

Check [here](http://caniuse.com) to see if a feature is widely-supported enough for your target audience.